# passing xmlnode to vb.net function

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have function in my asp.net/vb application with following signature:

```
Public Function ExtractText(node As XmlNode) As String
```

I want to call it/pass xmlnode. How to create an Xml node with value:

```
<mynode Id="7743" Type="context" StartNode="4356" EndNode="1234"></mynode>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way of doing this:

```
Dim xmlDoc as new XmlDocument()
Dim xmlElem = xmlDoc.CreateElement("mynode")
xmlElem.SetAttribute("Id","7743")
```

This returns:

```
<mynode Id="7743" />
```

Since the type `XmlElement` inherits from `XmlNode` you can simply pass this to your function:

```
ExtractText(xmlElem)
```